# How to make one option of a listbox add data to a new field

Tags: forms, events, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2010

I have a listbox in a Microsoft Access 2010 form.  The listbox has several options and the last one is 'Other'.

When someone selects 'Other' I want the user to be able to type in their data and have it push that data into a different field. Note, I do not want the user to *add* new options to the listbox.

For instance if the list box was a field called 'Browsers' and my choices were:  Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Other.  When the person selects Other, I want them to be able to type in 'Safari' in a field in my database called 'Browsers_Other'.

I cannot seem to figure this out.  It looks to be related to similar to 'Cascading Listbox' but I think it is different.  I am wondering if I need to have the action open up a sub-form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a text box bound to the `Browsers_Other` field.  I called my text box *txtOther*.

Then from the list box's After Update event, enable the text box when the list box selection is *"Other"*.  When the list box selection is anything else, disable the text box and set its value to Null.

```vb
Private Sub lstBrowser_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.lstBrowser.value = "Other" Then
        Me.txtOther.Enabled = True
        Me.txtOther.SetFocus
    Else
        Me.cmdSave.SetFocus
        Me.txtOther.Enabled = False
        Me.txtOther.value = Null
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I change the lstBrowser to my field it almost works.  It breaks on the cmdSave.  What is that command ?

Comment: `cmdSave` is just a command button.  Mine doesn't actually do anything ... it just gives me somewhere to `SetFocus` before I disable `txtOther`.

Comment: I did not quite understand that.  If I delete the line, the code works but it does not push the data into the field.  How do I actually get it to write to the field when I move to the next record ?

Comment: Open the property sheet for `txtOther` and check its Control Source. When I said "bound" text box, that means your form's record source includes a field named `Browsers_Other` and that field is the text box's Control Source.